# How can I remove the extra output from the subprocess call?

Tags: python, subprocess

My code is making an API request. In response, I get json and an additional output. How can I remove extra output from a response?

I use Linux OS and Python 3

```
import subprocess

url = "curl -k -u '{user}':'{password}' {url}api/v1/clusters/{cl_name}/alerts?fields=*\&Alert/state.in\(WARNING,CRITICAL\)\&sortBy=Alert/state".format(user=self.user, password=self.passwd, url=cluster.url, cl_name=cluster.name)
resp = subprocess.check_output(url,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

response looks like this:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   603    0   603    0     0   1419      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1470
14:03
{
        "cluster_name" : "test_clust1",
        "component_name" : "DATANODE",
        "definition_id" : 18,
        "definition_name" : "datanode_storage"
}
```

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I'm facing same issue.

Comment: Yes, you should redirect stderr log to null.
2>/dev/null - after the command

Comment: Why are you using curl and subprocess instead of a native Python solution like [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

Comment: Although, if you do use subprocess, it doesn't seem like you need to use `shell=True`, though I'm not an expert. Then you could use a native Python method to redirect stderr instead of `2>/dev/null`, like see [ShadowRanger's answer on "redirect the stdout of an third-party module to /dev/null"](/a/56980344/4518341)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you should redirect stderr log to null.
`2>/dev/null` - after the command